# In this case, how do I handle nil well?

Tags: crystal-lang

## Situation

I wrote the following code.

```
class Gear
  getter :chainring, :cog, :wheel

  def initialize(@chainring : Int32, @cog : Int32, @wheel : Wheel?)
  end

  def ratio
    chainring / cog.to_f
  end

  def gear_inches
    ratio * wheel.diameter
  end
end
```

Then the following compilation error occurs

```
$ crystal run  gear.cr 
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

In bicycle.cr:12:19

 12 | ratio * wheel.diameter
```

## Things I want to do

I want to fix this compilation error without using `try` method.

## What I tried, what I researched

1. Crystal language does not allow the use of safe navigation operator.
2. Execute the `diameter` method only if the wheel variable is truthy, as in TypeScript.An example is given below.

```
def gear_inches
  if wheel
    ratio * wheel.diameter
  else
    0
  end
end
```

That's it for questions.
I would appreciate any advice you can give me.

Answer (score 3):

In a concurrent program the value of an instance variable could change between any two accesses to it. `getter wheel` makes `wheel` just return the instance variable `@wheel`. So between checking `if wheel` and the second call in `wheel.diameter` Crystal cannot tell that the value couldn't have changed.

The usual solution to this is to assign the value to a local variable, which allows Crystal to reason about when the value cannot change:

```
record Wheel, diameter : Int32

class Gear
  getter :chainring, :cog, :wheel

  def initialize(@chainring : Int32, @cog : Int32, @wheel : Wheel?)
  end

  def ratio
    chainring / cog.to_f
  end

  def gear_inches
    (wheel = self.wheel) ? ratio * wheel.diameter : 0
  end
end

gear = Gear.new(1, 2, Wheel.new(3))
puts gear.gear_inches
```

In many situations a nice alternative is to see if you can find a default value to internally return for your optional field:

```
record Wheel, diameter : Int32

class Gear
  getter :chainring, :cog

  def initialize(@chainring : Int32, @cog : Int32, @wheel : Wheel?)
  end

  def ratio
    chainring / cog.to_f
  end

  def gear_inches
    ratio * wheel.diameter
  end
  
  private def wheel
    @wheel || Wheel.new(0)
  end
end

gear = Gear.new(1, 2, nil)
puts gear.gear_inches
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am filled with gratitude.

I didn't have any idea about concurrent programming.
I am glad to know why the program I wrote gave me a compile error.

Also, the code you answered was very easy to understand!
I am going to rewrite my code with this as a reference.

Thank you so much!